# Add specific plugin version in Gradle using 'Apply'

Tags: gradle

How to apply a specific plugin version using newer Gradle syntax? I would like to do something like this but this gives an error of unknown property 'version':

```
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api', version: '2.0.3'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new plugin syntax can be seen on the Gradle Plugins Repository page for the plugin you wish to apply: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api

> Using the plugins DSL:
>
> ```
> plugins {
>   id "com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api" version "6.1.3"
> }
> ```
>
> Using legacy plugin application:
>
> ```
> buildscript {
>   repositories {
>     maven {
>       url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
>     }
>   }
>   dependencies {
>     classpath "com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:6.1.3"
>   }
> }
>
> apply plugin: "com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api"
> ```

In your `build.gradle` file, apply the plugin with a `plugins` block near the top of your script:

```
plugins {
  id "com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api" version "2.0.3"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you have there is **not** new, it the [legacy plugin application](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:old_plugin_application)

To specify the version for the legacy way, you need to use the `buildscript { }` block:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:2.0.3"
  }
}

apply plugin: "com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api"
```